# Icepick for saving and restoring composed custom views

Tags: android, android-custom-view

Assuming that you have two custom views

```
class TopLevelCustomView extends LinearLayout {

    @State
    TopViewState state;

    TextView textView;

    NestedCustomView nestedView;

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        // How to save both text view info & nested view using icepick <-- query
        return saveInstanceState(this, super.onSaveInstanceState());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(restoreInstanceState(this, state));
        // How to restore both text view info & nested view using icepick <-- query
    }

}

class NestedCustomView extends LinearLayout {

    @State
    NestedViewState state;

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        // How to save both text view info & nested view using icepick <-- actual query
        return saveInstanceState(this, super.onSaveInstanceState());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(restoreInstanceState(this, state));
        // How to restore both text view info & nested view using icepick <-- actual query
    }

}
```

How to use Icepick and automatically save & restore view state for both the nested custom view & other view from `TopLevelCustomView`